# Read Uploaded Files Using Service

Tags: file-upload

I have web page, from web page user can upload multiple files and save it into Upload directory on server.
All uploaded file size is too large and i have to read contnet from all files, so it will take to much time.
Now what i want to do, i am planning to create one wcf service/win service which will frequently checked that are there any new uploaded files on server directory, if there are then take all files and read all files using thread.But confusion i am cofuse to manage files on server and win service if concurrent user frequenly upload files from web page, how can i manage directory priority for win service that which should be read.Please provide me your suggestion/any new concept to manage upload files.